# How do I test for two items in one Command Block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to test for two items in one Command Block. I tried this command:

```
execute if entity @e[type=item,dx=-2,dy=6,dz=-2,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:quartz"}}]
```

That is for just one item. How do I add a second one?

Comment: For whoever voted to close, i dont know what is unclear about this?

Answer (score 1):

Add another `if` clause to your `/execute`:

```
execute
  if entity @e[type=item,dx=-2,dy=6,dz=-2,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:quartz"}}]
  if entity @e[type=item,dx=-2,dy=6,dz=-2,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_block"}}]
run …
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a command block, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then type your second command.

Comment: I'm afraid that is incorrect. Command blocks only have room for one command.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Oh. I guess that is a Bedrock thing? Either that or I am dumb! Thanks for letting me know though.

Comment: @Potterton nah that doesnt work on bedrock either, guess your just dumb then (jk)

Comment: @Penguin  Thanks for the info! I rarely use Command Blocks, so I am certified dumb!